# Error in line of view in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is wrong with this line?

```
 echo "<a href="{{url('/delete',$list->id)}}">Delete</a>";
```

i am using laravel 5.2 framework. the error is unexpected `{` or expecting `';'`. if i remove this line the error doesont appear. so i guess the error is in this line

the actual code:

```
<?php
$user=new App\User();
$data=$user->all(array('id','fname','lname','contact'));
echo "<TABLE BORDER=2>";
echo "<TR><TD>S.N.</td><TD>Fname/td><TD>Lname</td><td><B>Contact</B></td><td><B>Options</B></td></TR>";

foreach($data as $list)
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $list->id;
    echo "<td>";
    echo $list->fname;
    echo "<td>";
    echo $list->lname;
    echo "<td>";
    echo $list->contact;
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href="{{url('/delete',$list->id)}}">Delete</a>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade file must has `.blade.php` extension.

In blade template you do not need to write `<?php ?>` tag.

`{{ 'statement' }}` means `<?php echo 'statement'; ?>`

Write your loop as below:-

```
@foreach($data as $list)  
    <tr>
    <td>
    {{ $list->id }}
    <td>
    {{ $list->fname}}
    <td>
    {{ $list->lname }}
    <td>
    {{ $list->contact }};
    <td>
    <a href="{{url('/delete',$list->id)}}">Delete</a>
@endforeach
```

Refer blade template [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade).

Answer (score 2):

Your actual problem is that you are opening a string with double quote `"` and using double quote inside it.

If you want to remove your problem just do this

```
echo '<a href="{{url("/delete",$list->id)}}">Delete</a>';
```

Note the difference between `"` and `'`

**Though**, if you want to use Blade refer to Ravi Hirani's answer.

Comment: ok. but it redirects to a different route `/laravel/public/%7B%7Burl(` instead it should be `/laravel/public/delete`